# Kendo UI (for JQuery) components fail when Vue app is mounted on surrounding div

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

I am adding some Vue interaction into an existing ASP.Net Core project that uses lots of Kendo UI for JQuery components.  I find that as soon as I mount an app on the surrounding div that the Kendo components stop working.  There are no errors in the console.  Native elements (input, select etc) do work OK and Vue itself is working perfectly.

Here is a link to a simple Kendo dojo that shows the issue in action - the numeric input stops responding: https://dojo.telerik.com/@gordon@devcloud.com.au/IvAlusuP/2

Any ideas on what the issue could?

EDIT

If I change the order of initialization then it works as expected.  In the ASP.Net forms I am using TagHelpers to create the components and these have a deferred option which puts the scripts needed to init the components into a section that is rendered by

```
@Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts(renderScriptTags: false)
```

The renderScriptTags option controls if the  tags are added.  In my case I have them off and can init the kendo components in my form ready function just after the Vue app is mounted.
This works but will mean extra work in all forms where I add some Vue.  It still does not explain why the components initally fail.